# Get playhead position based on pts

Tags: video, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, pts

I'm trying to determine if it is possible to get a playhead position based on the pts of a TS file.

Most articles I have found just talk about using ffmpeg and I'm not using that.

My understanding is that pts is based on the pcr, which is an optional field in the MPEG TS spec.  But given that can a frame's position be computed to seconds into a stream based on to pts.  If so, how do I go about the calculation?

Answer (score 1):

Not really, but maybe if you know the pts of the first frame. Then you can do the math. Note, pts will overflow every 26 hours or so, so you many need to check the entire file/manifest if you expect streams that long. In addition, the pts can be reset to any value at any point if the dicontinuity bit is set.

Comment: So how is it possible for players to calculate duration and determine seek position?  Those don't seem like the pts would play a huge role,but for seeking it has to check pts to know what segment to load, correct?

Comment: @Justin segment? So you are talking about HLS. With HLS you have a manifest file. This file should be used to create your scrub bar  it has the duration of each segment. These durations can be added together to determine total length., and to resolve position to turn time.

Comment: Does that still hold true with seeking?  I would image seeking would be a more involved process that includes converting seconds, or even milliseconds into a PTS to find the frame within a segment to start playback at.

Comment: Yes. Still true.  You can only start playing back at a key frame anyway. And ideally, a segment will only ever have one key frame at the start of the segment. So sub segment seeking has limited value.  If you want to implement sub segment seeking anyway, you can still use the same approach to select the segment, then get an offset based on pts where you only need to check one segment for integer overflows and pts discontinuity.

Comment: Saying you have segments that are 10 seconds in duration and you want to get at the frame that is 3 seconds in, it would seem that would be a more accurate way to find this.   Not even taking HLS into consideration, a single ts file that is 5 minutes long would need some sort of frame-accurate seek to the second at least.  I guess I'm still not quite wrapping my head around this.  Still looking for my "Ah Ha!" moment.

Comment: Think of it this way, a 5 minute video is 300000 milliseconds. If your display is not 300000 pixels wide, the user can not even select a position the precisely  using a mouse.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104434/discussion-between-justin-and-szatmary).

Comment: @Justin my contract rate is $200 usd an hour. :)